# How to convert numbers with comma to money format

Tags: php, function

I am trying to convert numbers from a database into money format, using the function money format.
The SQL query works fine and the output for

```
echo "$amount" is 800,600.00.
```

I have tried using

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $amount) . "\n";
```

but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function money_format() in C:\xampp\htdocs\loan\en\account\payment.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\loan\en\account\payment.php on line 14

My overall codes are:

```
<?php
include('../user/db.php');
$uploaduser = "ruxell4real";
$stmt =$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uploaduser);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result();
$result= $row->fetch_assoc();

$amount = $result['balance'];


setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $amount) . "\n";
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: function money_format: Warning
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Comment: @Mureinik am using PHP Version 7.4.3 and windows 10

Comment: @jspit what other function can  I use to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php

Comment: @Gabor, using number_format on the variable $amount returns an error: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\loan\en\account\payment.php on line 12

Comment: $amount = "-1800.12"; echo number_format($amount, 2, ",", "."); // result: -1.800,12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is a string of the form "800,600.00". This string cannot be converted into a float in this way. The comma must be removed for this. I use a simple str_replace for this.

```
$amount = "800,600.00";

$floatAmount = (float)str_replace(",","",$amount);
//test
var_dump($floatAmount);  //float(800600)
```

This float value can then be output in the required format with the corresponding functions/classes.

```
echo "number_format: ". number_format($floatAmount,2,".",","). "<br>";

$fmt = new \NumberFormatter("en_US", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo "NumberFormatter: ".$fmt->format($floatAmount) . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
number_format: 800,600.00
NumberFormatter: $800,600.00
```